# How to trigger useEffect when passing props back to parent component

Tags: react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

This question is for React Navigation 5 in React Native app. When passing a props back to parent screen, how to setup trigger in parent screen for `useEffect`? Here is an example:

```
Child Screen

_onPress = (country, country_code, calling_code) => {
    const { navigation, route } = this.props;
    navigation.navigate("parent"
    {select:{
        country_name: country,
        country_code: country_code,
        calling_code: calling_code
    });
};
```

on parent component. `useEffect` is used to do something after the props `select` is passed back from the child screen:

```
useEffect(()=> {
   if (route.params?.select?) {
      //do something after select is passed back
   }
}, [what is the trigger?])  //<<==how to setup trigger for useEffect?. [] did not work.
```

How to setup trigger in parent component for useEffect? Tried to use [] which shall trigger with any reload but it did not work. Shall the same props `select` be passed from parent component to child screen and passed back to parent component again after being updated in child screen? Is `select`  a  trigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since you are using React Navigation 5, what you can do is to replace useEffect with [useFocusEffect](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/), and your functions will be called every time when the user arrives/returns to the parent screen.

First import useFocusEffect at the top of your file like this:

```js
import { useFocusEffect } from "@react-navigation/native"
```

then replace useEffect with useFocusEffect like this:

```js
 useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      if (route.params?.select?) {
      //do something after select is passed back
   }
      return () => {
        // Here you can do something when the screen is unfocused such as clearing event listners but you can also leave it empty if you want
       
      };
    }, [])
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

One more thing you can do is to set the navigation state params when you are moving to the child screen from Parent Screen like this.

```
 props.navigation.navigate('ChildScreen', {onNewCreate});
```

In the child component just called this

```
select:{
    country_name: country,
    country_code: country_code,
    calling_code: calling_code
}


 props.navigation.state.params.onNewCreate(select);
```

And in the Parent component just define onNewCreate() and you can do what you want.

```
 const onNewCreate = async (select) => {
//You can do what you want here with select}
```

Comment: This is the pattern being used and it causes warning in react navigation 5.x.